# how to match nested regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match WikiMedia files markups which I meet in following situation:

```
[[ref1]] text [[Datei:Panorama2München.JPG der [[Frauenkirche (München)|Frauenkirche]] aus in Blickrichtung Südosten]] text [[ref2]].
```

---

I Want to match

```
[[Datei:Panorama2München.JPG der [[Frauenkirche (München)|Frauenkirche]] aus in Blickrichtung Südosten]]
```

Comment: I don't think regex is the best solution for this. A lexer is normally a much better way of dealing with constructs like this since there is a strict syntax. Regex is notoriously bad for dealing with nesting like this in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what parts are constant? does all the strings you want to match start with "[[Datie" and have the exact amount on brackets? If so you can try this `[[Datei.*[[.*]].*]]`. And if its the one after "text" the try `text [[.*[[.*]].*]]`.
But be aware that if you don't know the number of brackets then it can be tricky, but you need some assumption about them, because it's impossible to make a regular expression that matches an unknown amount of brackets. (For that you will need a stack - managed by you.)